# Make Backup of Data(Ms Access database) from Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, netbeans, backup, ms-access-2007

I am making an inventory system. I need to make backup of database file which is ms access database file. I need to make backup frequently so that data could be preserved. Please give me some information on how will I make backup and also guide me to where to store it as backup file.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Where to store backup I mean if windows crash where should it be placed i-e database file which could be recovered. 
And how will I make copy from application automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backing up an Access databse is just making a copy of its .mdb file (and I suggest you store more than one copy - for example 10 last copies). Usual filesystem functions should work. As to where store the backups... it's up to you. How would we know?

Comment: Using the file system will work as long as it's not open. If it's open, the resulting copy may or may not be internally consistent.

Comment: I've been doing backups of MsAccess database thrice a day for three years now and never come across an inconsistent backup. On the other hand, Access itself corrupts it's own database couple of times each month.

Comment: Then you've never done a backup when the file is open with an edit lock. Luck? Perhaps not -- maybe you do something to make sure there aren't any edit locks when you copy the file. But the point is that you can't guarantee that this is the case 100% of the time. Anybody who has ever had to restore data from backups knows how often your backups turn out to not have the data in them you assume they do, so why take that risk?

Comment: Maybe luck, who knows. Although there are people logged into this database pretty much all the time. Personally I don't trust Access at all as far as data integrity is concerned, need to upkeep this one legacy app unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Click Microsoft office button -> Manage-> Back Up Database -> Enter backup database name in File Dialog -> Save

http://databases.about.com/od/tutorials/ht/backup_access.htm

Comment: How does one do that from a Java Desktop Application, as in the actual question being asked? Keep in mind also that this answer is version-specific -- A2003 was the first to offer a backup function, but it is on the TOOLS | DATABASE UTILITIES menu, and A2010 changes the Office menu back to the more familiar FILE menu.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting. As the question was tagged as ms-access-2007 and I use same version, I ended up posting solution for specific version.